# file_url() produces no output

Tags: theming

I have a custom block, and a *block--inline-block--hero-video.html.twig* template file. The block has a *field_video* field.

If I put `{{content.field_video[0]}}` in my theme, the output is the following (as expected).

```html
<span class="file file--mime-video-mp4 file--video">
  <a href="/sites/default/files/2023-09/birdcode-intro-1280.mp4" type="video/mp4">birdcode-intro-1280.mp4</a>
</span>
<span>(5.72 MB)</span>
```

I am looking to get only `/sites/default/files/2023-09/birdcode-intro-1280.mp4`.

According to [Functions in Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/functions-in-twig-templates#s-file-urluri), the following should work.

```
{{ file_url(content.field_video.entity.uri.value) }}
```

Yet, that produces `null`, like the following markup.

```
{{ file_url(content.field_video.entity.uri.value) }}
{{ file_url(content.field_video[0].entity.uri.value) }}
{{ file_url(content.field_video[0].entity.uri )}}
```

It should be noted that you can define the field display as "URL" rather than "Generic file" in the admin interface, and if you do that, then `{{content.field_video[0]}}` will show `/sites/default/files/2023-09/birdcode-intro-1280.mp4`.

Nonetheless, I would like to extract the file URL in Twig in the case the field display is a generic file.

Comment: I've added a solution for *block.html.twig* to the linked topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
file_url(content.field_video['#items'].entity.uri.value)
```

Note this does not directly support translations.